# Creating a new local user from vCenter (with vSphere 5.1)

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I am trying to add a new local user from vCenter. I could not find how to do it.

I dont have the "Users & Groups" tab.

Important note, I do not want to join the vCenter to the domain. I really want to create a local user.

EDIT: I use vSphere 5.1

Comment: Which version of vSphere are you using?

Comment: I use vSphere 5.1

Comment: Thought about getting some training or reading the documentation?

Comment: I think that this article on 4.1 is still applicable in 5.1. I just used it to add a local user. http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2005626

Comment: I just deleted an answer that copy/pasted https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.security.doc%2FGUID-D42B830C-3156-4C5E-80EF-A7DA449A2E9F.html

Answer (score 4):

You must connect with SSO administrator login to see the Users and Groups, default is administrator@vsphere.local

Answer (score 2):

**In the Web Client**

1. Browse to Administration > Access > SSO Users and Groups in the vSphere Web Client.
2. On the Users tab, click the New User icon.(The green + sign)
3. Type a user name and password for the new user.
   You cannot change the user name after you create a user.
   The password must meet the password policy requirements for the system.
4. (Optional) Type the first name and last name of the new user.
5. Type the email address for the new user.
6. Select the type of permissions the user is granted.
   User roles are incremental. More powerful roles are supersets of weaker roles.

Comment: Are you talking about the vCenter web based appliance on port 5480? If so, I do not find anything you're talking about. Else, which web client?

Comment: Yes, are you sure you're using 5.1? Because in 5.0 you didn't have these options - so I would verify that you are in fact running 5.0. If you did an upgrade from 5.0 to 5.1 make sure you updated your web client. Or are you just managing one ESXi server? If so, login with the vSphere Client then - 
1. Click the Local Users & Groups tab and click Users.
2. Right-click anywhere in the Users table and click Add.
3. Enter a login, a user name, and a password.

Comment: It looks like I must use the console of the vCenter appliance to create a new user with "useradd" command.